# Finding Currently Focused Application

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I've been using this code to try and get the current process that's running (other that my application).

All over the internet it's been telling me to use the code below but it seems to be giving me issues.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
{
    const int nChars = 256;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
    {
     return Buff.ToString();
    }
  return null;
}
```

It's giving me two errors.

> Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
>
> The modifier 'extern' is not valid for this item

Could anybody help?

Comment: www.pinvoke.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Rahul, put your code inside the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
        {
            const int nChars = 256;
            StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
            IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

            if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
            {
                return Buff.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string title = GetActiveWindowTitle();
            label1.Text = title;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks! I was doing that, but I don't know if it was the importing that I messed up but it's working now,

Answer (score 1):

> Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

If you are getting this error then most probably you are defining or declaring those method within `namespace` and not within your `class` body

Comment: Even within my `public partial class MainForm : Form` it gives me that error @Rahul

Comment: @SuperNovaa41, then post the entire code and not a extract which is vouge

Comment: I'm just not quite sure where I should put it, in a method or just within the class? @Rahul